# Spring Data Cassandra Custom Read Converter for Enum called for non-enum fields

Tags: cassandra, spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

I have a custom read converter implemented as follows:

```
public class ActivityTraceStageReadConverter implements Converter<String, ActivityTraceStage> {
    @Override
    public ActivityTraceStage convert(String stage) {
        return ActivityTraceStage.valueOf(stage.toUpperCase());
    }
}
```

The values for the specific column are stored in lowercase, hence the `.toUpperCase()` in the converter. I have the converter registered as follows:

```
@Override
public CustomConversions customConversions() {
    return new CustomConversions(Arrays.asList(
            new ActivityTraceStageReadConverter()
    ));
}
```

The problem I'm running into is that this converter is being executed for every varchar column on the table, not just for columns that map to `ActivityTraceStage` on the specific Table. Is there something I need to do to get this converter to only run for one specific field? I figured it would be smart enough to only execute it for `ActivityTraceStage` fields, but I must be missing something here.

Comment: Which version of Spring Data for Apache Cassandra are you using? Add `@ReadingConverter` to hint Spring Data to use the converter only when reading from Cassandra.

Comment: That was it. Just needed the @ReadingConverter annotation. Thanks!